# Página não encontrada para Categoria de Post type no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types

Estou aprendendo a criar um tema no Wordpress e criei um **Post Type** personalizado. Dentro da página listei as categorias criadas somente para este **Post Type** específico. Só que não sei como criar um arquivo que se comporte como o **category.php** só que para essas categorias específicas do **Post Type** criado.

Não sei se fui clara, mas me ajudem pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A documentação do wordpress fornece uma sobre [hierarquia dos arquivos do tema](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) que pode te ajudar, mas acredito que o arquivo que você deseja criar irá se chamar `taxonomy-SLUG_DA_TAXONOMIA.php`.

Abaixo uma imagem que resume bem quais arquivos são usados e em qual ordem (na falta de um ele tenta o próximo, sempre parando no index.php).

[image: Hierarquia dos arquivos de tema WP]

Comment: Pois é, eu criei o arquivo dessa maneira, mesmo assim vai pra 404. Talvez eu tenha errado no functions.php ou na configuração de links permantentes


`functions.php: register_taxonomy('produto_category','produto', $args);`

Comment: Se vai pra 404 o problema não é o arquivo mesmo, é o endereço ou como você criou a taxonomia. Se em `$args` você não esta colocando `query_vars` como falso ou alterando o valor de `rewrite` a categoria deveria ser acessível por `/produto_category/SLUG` ou por isso com algum prefixo se você configurou assim nos `Links Permanentes`.